# ios xamarin derived class override events

Tags: ios, class, overriding, xamarin

I want to build my own specialized class for UIBarButtonItem and I have done this:

```
public class myUIBarButtonItem: UIBarButtonItem {
UIImage _image { get; set;}
UIBarButtonItemStyle _style { get; set;}
string _title { get; set; }
public myUIBarButtonItem(UIImage mImage,UIBarButtonItemStyle mStyle, string mTitle) 
   : base()
{
_image = mImage;
_style = mStyle;
_title = mTitle;
UITextAttributes myTextAttrib = new UITextAttributes();
myTextAttrib.Font = UIFont.FromName("Arial",12);
myTextAttrib.TextColor = UIColor.FromRGB(202,185,131);
this.SetTitleTextAttributes (myTextAttrib, UIControlState.Normal);
this.Image = _image;
this.Title = _title;
}
}
```

I would to override base class events like Clicked and I don't know how to approach. A piece of sample code will be also appreciate on how to use then the class with the new event handler.
Thanks in advance.
Max

Answer (score 0):

UIBarButtonItem exposes Clicked event:

```
Clicked += (object sender, EventArgs e) => {
    new UIAlertView("Bar button tapped", "", null, "OK", null).Show();
};
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not usual to override an event so please provide more information on why you wish to override it.

If you want to remove the clicked event or do something extra there you could replace it with 'new' but I would assume this is not what you are after:

```
public class CustomBarButton : UIBarButtonItem
{
    public new event EventHandler Clicked
    {
        add
        {
//              base.Clicked += value;
        }
        remove
        {
//              base.Clicked -= value;
        }
    }
}
```